# Doctrine2 - relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm, yaml

I'm developing an application, which is looking for optimal route and timetable in public transport. I have some experience about Doctrine1, but it's my first time with Doctrine2. There is soem new fields to describe relations (mappedBy and inversedBy) and also some new ways of mapping.

I have following code:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery("SELECT partial cls.{stop}, partial t.{arriveTime, departureTime} FROM \Entities\Timetable t 
JOIN t.ride r
JOIN t.carrierLineStop cls
WHERE t.departureTime>=:time AND 
r.idCarrierLine=:carrierLine AND 
(cls.idStop=:firstStop OR cls.idStop=:lastStop)");
$query->setParameters(array(
    'time' => $time,
    'carrierLine' => $path->getLine(),
    'firstStop' => $path->getFirstStop(),
    'lastStop' => $path->getLastStop()
));
```

When I try to execute that script I've got an error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 24 near '}, partial t.{arriveTime,': Error: There is no mapped field named 'stop' on class Entities\CarrierLineStop.
```

Mapping files:

```
Entities\CarrierLineStop:
type: entity
table: carrier_line_stop
fields:
    idCarrierLineStop:
        id: true
        type: integer
        unsigned: false
        nullable: false
        column: id_carrier_line_stop
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
    nextStop:
        type: integer
        unsigned: false
        nullable: true
        column: next_stop
manyToOne:
    idCarrierLine:
        targetEntity: Entities\CarrierLine
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            id_carrier_line:
                referencedColumnName: id_carrier_line
        orphanRemoval: false
    stop:
        column: id_stop
        targetEntity: Entities\Stop
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: carrierLineStop
        joinColumns:
            id_stop:
                referencedColumnName: id_stop
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

-

```
Entities\Stop:
type: entity
table: stop
fields:
    idStop:
        id: true
        type: integer
        unsigned: false
        nullable: false
        column: id_stop
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
    name:
        type: string
        length: 45
        fixed: false
        nullable: true
    miejscowosc:
        type: string
        length: 45
        fixed: false
        nullable: true
    latitude:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
    longitude:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
oneToMany:
    carrierLineStop:
        targetEntity: Entities\CarrierLineStop
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: stop
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            id_stop:
                referencedColumnName: id_stop
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I have no idea about where the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the keyword partial works only on entity fields (like idCarrierLineStop and nextStop), stop is a composite field.

If you want to leave the query like this you should delete the ManyToOne mapping and add a field mapping with id_stop or alternatively add a JOIN with the Stop entity in the query and return its id in place of cls.{stop}

Comment: finally I've solved this problem with small modification in Doctrine core class - I've made one of the class (don't remember which) to read also relation's as mapping fields. I know that it is not an elegent solution, but I don't have another idea to make it works